# javafx - events blocking other events from getting handled?

Tags: java, user-interface, events, javafx, handler

I am creating a Minesweeper clone for fun w/ javafx and if anyone has played the original game they might recall that when you press down on a tile and move around, the other tiles behave as if they are also being pressed... and if you let go - the node your mouse is currently over will be clicked even though you originally pressed down on an entirely different node. I am having a hard time recreating this and I need some help.

I am using a global event handler class, and I'm not really sure if this is good or really bad... however, it feels right to have the events for my clone being handled separately. I have tried using methods on the node which the event occurred, like startFullDrag() or startDragAndDrop() which I think will allow other events to occur or be used by other nodes? I thought by calling these methods on the event origin node it would allow other events to be handled or information to be sent to the end node, but nothing really worked. Before that approach, I tried to handle the events in a nested manner, every approach ends up with the drag event not allowing anything to happen.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can get this feature implemented... I am kind of at a brick wall. If I was not clear about something please ask and I will try and clarify. Also any critiques on my code is much appreciated. I am always looking to improve.

[My clone (so far) and all of its classes on Gist.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/16d044fb2d5727cd68f8)

Comment: Having only one event handler for all nodes is ok. I don;t understand why are you trying to use drag events, in original minesweeper there is no dragging behavior. Instead of firing new events to neighbour nodes, build a loop to traverse neighbour nodes for checking mines and mine hint numbers and do node.setOpened or setPressed etc. If it is some homework task, try to do it yourself.

Comment: I don't have a problem with finding mines and all that jazz, I'm talking about a little nuance in every Minesweeper game I've played where when you left click & hold on a tile, then move your mouse around while holding left-click down every node you go to will act pressed down until you release to expose the potential mine or w/e. In Java w/ any button (incl. ToggleButton) this does not happen, when you click & hold & drag other tiles don't become pressed down. So I'm trying to emulate that old subtle thing from the game. Do you know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment above was much more helpful to understand what you meant in the question, since, of course, I have also used to play the Minesweeper ;).

The `startFullDrag()` is a way to go:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage )
{

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragDetectedHandler = (( MouseEvent event ) ->
    {
        (( ToggleButton ) event.getSource()).startFullDrag();
    });

    EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> dragEnteredHandler = (( MouseDragEvent event ) ->
    {
        (( ToggleButton ) event.getSource()).setSelected( true );
    });

    EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> onMouseDragHandler = (( MouseDragEvent event ) ->
    {
        (( ToggleButton ) event.getSource()).fire();
    });

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> onActionHandler = (( ActionEvent event ) ->
    {
        ToggleButton b = ( ToggleButton ) event.getSource();
        System.out.println( "Action on " + b.getText() );

        // without the following settings the button is not getting selected
        // and focused when fire() is triggered within onMouseDragHandler.
        b.setSelected( true );
        b.requestFocus();
    });

    VBox vBox = new VBox();

    ToggleButton tb1 = new ToggleButton( "A" );
    ToggleButton tb2 = new ToggleButton( "B" );
    ToggleButton tb3 = new ToggleButton( "C" );

    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    tb1.setToggleGroup( group );
    tb2.setToggleGroup( group );
    tb3.setToggleGroup( group );

    tb1.setOnAction( onActionHandler );
    tb2.setOnAction( onActionHandler );
    tb3.setOnAction( onActionHandler );

    tb1.setOnDragDetected( dragDetectedHandler );
    tb2.setOnDragDetected( dragDetectedHandler );
    tb3.setOnDragDetected( dragDetectedHandler );

    tb1.setOnMouseDragEntered( dragEnteredHandler );
    tb2.setOnMouseDragEntered( dragEnteredHandler );
    tb3.setOnMouseDragEntered( dragEnteredHandler );

    tb1.setOnMouseDragReleased( onMouseDragHandler );
    tb2.setOnMouseDragReleased( onMouseDragHandler );
    tb3.setOnMouseDragReleased( onMouseDragHandler );

    vBox.getChildren().addAll( tb1, tb2, tb3 );

    Scene scene = new Scene( vBox, 150, 150 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**EDIT: questions in the comment.**

> Is this only possible when you have multiple event handlers? Would I not be able to do this in one event handler?

You can have one common event handler that catches all event types, but then you need to check the event type to do different tasks based on this type, like

```
if (event.getEventType().equals( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)) {
    // do on mouse click
} else if (event.getEventType().equals( MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED)) {
    // do other
}
```

> Also why does this only work with a ToggleGroup?

The javadoc of `ToggleGroup` states:

> A class which contains a reference to all Toggles whose selected
>   variables should be managed such that only a single Toggle within the
>   ToggleGroup may be selected at any one time.

Without it, you need to manage the single selection of toggle buttons yourself.

Comment: Is this only possible when you have multiple event handlers? Would I not be able to do this in one event handler? Also why does this only work with a ToggleGroup? However a huge problem with a ToggleGroup is that only one Tile can be selected so I can't play Minesweeper.